# FrameLayout.getId() on a null object

Tags: android

I have method loadFragment(); In which i load the DashboardFragment which is having a framelayout widget. But inside the loadFragment() i get a null pointer exception and i dont know why. I have attached the loadFragment(). please help me. Thanks!

The error is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.FrameLayout.getId()' on a null object reference.
>               at com.qdocs.smartschool.fragments.StudentDashboardFragment.loadFragment(StudentDashboardFragment.java:241)

```
loadFragment(new DashboardCalender());

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // load fragment
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(calenderFrame.getId(), fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

The studentDashboardFragment class

```
package com.qdocs.smartschool.fragments;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.qdocs.smartschool.R;
import com.qdocs.smartschool.students.StudentAttendance;
import com.qdocs.smartschool.students.StudentHomework;
import com.qdocs.smartschool.students.StudentTasks;
import com.qdocs.smartschool.utils.Constants;
import com.qdocs.smartschool.utils.Utility;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

public class StudentDashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    RelativeLayout attendanceLayout, homeworkLayout, pendingTaskLayout;
    TextView attendanceValue, homeworkValue, pendingTaskValue;
    CardView attendanceCard, homeworkCard, pendingTaskCard;
    FrameLayout calenderFrame;

    public Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    public StudentDashboardFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadData();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_dashboard_fragment, container, false);

        attendanceLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_fragment_attendanceView);
        homeworkLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_fragment_homeworkView);
        pendingTaskLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_fragment_pendingTaskView);

        attendanceCard = mainView.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_fragment_attendanceCard);
        homeworkCard = mainView.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_fragment_homeworkCard);
        pendingTaskCard = mainView.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_fragment_pendingTaskCard);

        attendanceValue = mainView.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_fragment_attendance_value);
        homeworkValue = mainView.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_fragment_homework_value);
        pendingTaskValue = mainView.findViewById(R.id.student_dashboard_fragment_pendingTask_value);

        calenderFrame = mainView.findViewById(R.id.dashboardViewPager);

        loadData();

        attendanceLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent asd = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), StudentAttendance.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(asd);
            }
        });

        homeworkLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent asd = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), StudentHomework.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(asd);
            }
        });

        pendingTaskLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent asd = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), StudentTasks.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(asd);
            }
        });
        Log.e("STATUS", "onCreateView");
        return mainView;
    }

    private void loadData() {
        //decorate();
        loadFragment(new DashboardCalender());

        params.put("student_id", Utility.getSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Constants.studentId));
        params.put("date_from", getDateOfMonth(new Date(), "first"));
        params.put("date_to", getDateOfMonth(new Date(), "last"));
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(params);
        Log.e("params ", obj.toString());
        getDataFromApi(obj.toString());

        try {
            JSONArray modulesArray = new JSONArray(Utility.getSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Constants.modulesArray));

            if(modulesArray.length() != 0) {
                ArrayList<String> moduleCodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> moduleStatusList = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i<modulesArray.length(); i++) {
                    if(modulesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("short_code").equals("student_attendance")
                        && modulesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("is_active").equals("0") ) {
                        attendanceCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } if(modulesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("short_code").equals("homework")
                            && modulesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("is_active").equals("0") ) {
                        homeworkCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } if(modulesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("short_code").equals("calendar_to_do_list")
                            && modulesArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("is_active").equals("0") ) {
                        pendingTaskCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        calenderFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }
    private void getDataFromApi (String bodyParams) {

        Log.e("RESULT PARAMS", bodyParams);
        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setMessage("Loading");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

        final String requestBody = bodyParams;
        String url = Utility.getSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "apiUrl") + Constants.getDashboardUrl;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    try {
                        Log.e("Result", result);
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                        //TODO success
                        String success = "1"; //object.getString("success");
                        if (success.equals("1")) {
                            if(object.getString("attendence_type").equals("0")){
                                attendanceValue.setText(object.getString("student_attendence_percentage") + "%");
                            }else{
                                attendanceCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                            homeworkValue.setText(object.getString("student_homework_incomplete"));
                            pendingTaskValue.setText(object.getString("student_incomplete_task"));

                            String classid = object.getString("class_id");
                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Constants.classId, classid);
                            Utility.setSharedPreference(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Constants.sectionId, object.getString("section_id"));


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), object.getString("errorMsg"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.string.noInternetMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                pd.dismiss();
                Log.e("Volley Error", volleyError.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.slowInternetMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                headers.put("Client-Service", Constants.clientService);
                headers.put("Auth-Key", Constants.authKey);
                headers.put("Content-Type", Constants.contentType);
                headers.put("User-ID", Utility.getSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "userId"));
                headers.put("Authorization", Utility.getSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "accessToken"));
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());//Creating a Request Queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);//Adding request to the queue
    }

    private void decorate() {
        attendanceLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.defaultSecondaryColour));
        homeworkLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.defaultSecondaryColour));
        pendingTaskLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.defaultSecondaryColour));
    }

    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // load fragment
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//        transaction.replace(calenderFrame.getId(), fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public static String getDateOfMonth(Date date, String index){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        if(index.equals("first")) {
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        } else {
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
    }
}
```

The xml containing viewpager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_attendanceCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/CustomCardView"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_attendanceView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_attendanceView_icon"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_attendance"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_attendance"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_attendance_head"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:gravity="start|center"
                            android:paddingStart="5dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/textHeading"
                            android:text="@string/attendance"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:gravity="start|center"
                            android:paddingStart="5dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/thisMonth"
                            android:textColor="@color/textHeading"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_attendance_head"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_attendance_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="22sp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/textHeading"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_homeworkCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/CustomCardView"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_homeworkView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_homeworkView_icon"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_homework"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_homework"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_homework_head"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="17sp"
                            android:gravity="start|center"
                            android:paddingStart="5dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/textHeading"
                            android:text="@string/homework"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:gravity="start|center"
                            android:paddingStart="5dp"
                            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                            android:text="@string/incomplete"
                            android:textColor="@color/textHeading"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_homework_head"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_homework_value"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="22sp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/textHeading"
                            />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_pendingTaskCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/CustomCardView"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_pendingTaskView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_pendingTaskView_icon"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_pandingtask"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_pendingTask"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_pendingTask_head"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="17sp"
                                android:gravity="start|center"
                                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/textHeading"
                                android:text="@string/pendingTask" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:gravity="start|center"
                                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                                android:text="@string/today"
                                android:textColor="@color/textHeading"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_pendingTask_head" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/student_dashboard_fragment_pendingTask_value"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textSize="22sp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/textHeading"
                                />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/dashboardViewPager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/textHeading"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>



            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post some more code. Have you initialized calenderFrame?

Comment: yes i have initialized it.

Comment: calenderFrame = mainView.findViewById(R.id.dashboardViewPager);  see i have initialized it

Comment: what is mainview? how have you initalized it?

Comment: have you initialized calenderFrame before calling loadFragment?

Comment: yes i have intitalized the calendarFrame with the viewpager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I understand the null pointer exceptions but i am not able to understand where i went wrong.@Ryan

Comment: I have edited the question @Keshv1234. please check the studentDashboardFragment class and help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the error is quite self-explanatory. `calenderFrame` is null, meaning that you never initialized it.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning the codes but i have initialized it.    calenderFrame = mainView.findViewById(R.id.dashboardViewPager);

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. In onCreate() of fragment my code was calling the loadFragment() method before  initializing the calenderFrame.

Comment: I had already mentioned this in one of my comments. Then why posting this as answer?